# When trying to get data with whereArrayContains query using Firebase in Kotlin, an empty list comes up

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I save my data in firebase using the following code.

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFireStoreInstance(): FirebaseFirestore {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    }
```

my firebase instance

```
 private val database: FirebaseFirestore

           override suspend fun saveTask(taskModel: TaskModel): Result<Unit> {

        return kotlin.runCatching {


            val currentUserRef = database.collection("Users").document(taskModel.currentUser)
            val constructionSiteRef =
                currentUserRef.collection("construcitonName").document(taskModel.constructionArea)
            val postsRef =
                constructionSiteRef.collection("task").document(taskModel.day)

            currentUserRef.set(hashMapOf("dummyField" to "dummyValue"))
            constructionSiteRef.set(hashMapOf("dummyField" to "dummyValue"))
            postsRef.set(hashMapOf("dummyField" to "dummyValue"))

            val taskRef = postsRef.collection("taskId").document(taskModel.taskId.toString())

            val post = hashMapOf(
                "message" to taskModel.message,
                "title" to taskModel.title,
                "day" to taskModel.day,
                "taskId" to taskModel.taskId,
                "workerList" to taskModel.workerList,
                "currentUser" to taskModel.currentUser,
                "constructionArea" to taskModel.constructionArea,
            )

            taskRef.set(post).await()
        }
    }
```

I can see the data I saved in firebase, and when I create a reference, I can retrieve it with another function. However, one of the variables I saved is a list, and when I try to retrieve all documents containing a value in this list, it returns an empty list. So, for example, when I try to retrieve all documents containing the value "Moulders" in the workerList, it returns an empty list. While doing this, I use the getTasksWithWorker function and it is as follows.

```
    override suspend fun getTasksWithWorker(worker: String): Result<List<TaskModel>> {
        return kotlin.runCatching {
            val tasks = mutableListOf<TaskModel>()

            val querySnapshot = database.collection("task")
                .whereArrayContains("workerList", worker)
                .get()
                .await()

            for (document in querySnapshot.documents) {
                val task = document.toObject(TaskModel::class.java)
                task?.let {
                    tasks.add(it)
                }
            }
            tasks
        }
    }
```

also my firebase database
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbo3A.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEv5M.png)

While working in debug mode, I saw a callback telling me to go to Firebase Indexes. I added it as shown in the picture. The callback disappeared, but this time an empty list started returning.

[Firebase Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl2vP.png)

Then, an empty list was returned as shown below. Also, the database setting section is marked in red.
I got the error.
`Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreSettings.toString()`
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Zfs.png)

Comment: Please provide the versions of each relevant dependency and include the code that initialises Firebase, in particular the `database` value - where does it come from? where is it set? etc.

Comment: I added my firebase instance.By the way, I can save and read data to Firebase in the project, only I have not done the 'whereArrayContains' query before.